# Converting mysql query to be used in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am newbie in mysql and vb.net and have this query:

```
select `db_employee`.`firstName` as `firstName`, `db_employee`.`lastName` as `lastName`,
       `tbl_employment`.`position` as `position`
  from (`db_employee` `db_employee`
  inner join `tbl_employment` `tbl_employment` on (`tbl_employment`.`ctrlID` = `db_employee`.`ctrlID`))
 where (`tbl_employment`.`companyName` like 'MES%')
```

And I want to convert it to be used here:

```
Dim MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
MySqlConn.ConnectionString = connStr
Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dbdataset As New DataTable
Dim bsource As New BindingSource
MySqlConn.Open()
Dim query As String
query = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code for displaying data... i hope this what you want.. :)

```
Dim cn As SqlConn= New SqlConn("Connecting String")
    Dim cmd As sqlCommand
     Dim dr As sqlDataReader
cn.open()
cmd = New sqlCommand("select * from table or your query, cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dr.Read()
            textbox1.Text = dr(1).ToString()
cn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with the MySQL provider you're using.  This will create your connection, command and data reader and close and dispose of everything properly.  If you want a DataTable instance, you can load it from the DataReader.

```
    Using conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("YourConnectionString")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "select db_employee.firstName as firstName, " & _
                                        "db_employee.lastName as lastName, " & _
                                        "tbl_employment.position as position " & _
                                        "from db_employee db_employee " & _
                                        "inner join tbl_employment tbl_employment on tbl_employment.ctrlID = db_employee.ctrlID " & _
                                        "where tbl_employment.companyName like 'MES%' "

            ' Get a data reader that you can loop over or load a data table with
            Dim dr As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

            ' How to read with a DataReader
            While dr.Read
                ' Do something with this
                Dim lastName As String = dr("lastName")

            End While


        End Using

        conn.Close()
    End Using
```